# Flip Menu stayed always in center horizontally (when i open or close)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**My code :**

```js
var currentPage = 0;
$('.book')
.on('click', '.active', nextPage)
.on('click', '.flipped', prevPage);
$('.book').hammer().on("swipeleft", nextPage);
$('.book').hammer().on("swiperight", prevPage);

function prevPage() {
  $('.flipped')
    .last()
    .removeClass('flipped')
    .addClass('active')
    .siblings('.page')
    .removeClass('active')
  $('.scene')
    .addClass('right-set').css("left", "0px");
}

function nextPage() {
  $('.active')
    .removeClass('active')
    .addClass('flipped')
    .next('.page')
    .addClass('active')
    .siblings()
  $('.scene')
    .addClass('left-set').css("left", "490px");
}
```

```css
.scene {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.book {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.page {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s -webkit-transform;
  transition: 1.5s transform;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;  
  -ms-transform-origin: left center;  
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.page.active {
  z-index: 1;
}
.page.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.page.flipped:last-of-type {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class-col-md-12>
  <div class="scene" id="scene">
    <article class="book">
    <section class="page active">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>    
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>    
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>    
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="front">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>    
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="front">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>    
    </section>
    <section class="page right-set">
      <div class="front">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png">
      </div>
    </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

When we clicked on single image it will open and double image will be shown.

When there is double image the whole block should be center and on single image it will also in center horizontally.

This is a [flip menu](https://codepen.io/arshabhaarya/pen/aYjrdQ) and it is clickable.

**Is it possible to center this menu when it is opened and closed ?**

Comment: you need to revisit your codes and post relevant data. I am not able to run your code snippet added in the question...

Comment: you can also check on this https://codepen.io/arshabhaarya/pen/aYjrdQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Your JS Functions Like This

```
function prevPage() {
$('.flipped')
    .last()
    .removeClass('flipped')
    .addClass('active')
    .siblings('.page')
    .removeClass('active')
$('.scene')
    .addClass('right-set').css("left", "0px");

$('#scene').animate({
    'margin-left': '50%'
});

if ($('section.page:nth-child(1)').hasClass('active') == true) {
    $('#scene').animate({
        'left': '0px',
        'margin-left': '35%'
    });
}


}

function nextPage() {
    $('.active')
        .removeClass('active')
        .addClass('flipped')
        .next('.page')
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings()
    $('.scene')
        .addClass('left-set').css("left", "490px");

$('#scene').animate({
    'margin-left': '50%'
});

if ($('.right-set').hasClass('flipped') == true) {
    $('#scene').animate({
        'left': '0px',
        'margin-left': '65%'
    });
}

}
```